# GET API call working in webbrowser or postman but not jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue since yesterday calling my API with jquery code.

When I call GET http://sub.domain.com/congresses/ID via my web browser (chrome and safari), it works fine.

When I call the same route via a jquery call, all I get is "GET http://sub.domain.com/congresses/ID NET::ERR_FAILED"

I didn't get any log in my apache access.log nor error log (I host the front-end and the API).

Here is my jquery code :

```
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "http://sub.domain.com/congresses/17",
                dataType: "application/json",
                method: "GET",
                crossDomain: true,
                success : function(data){
                        populateApp(data);
                },
                error : function(){
                        populateApp(local_data);
                }
        });
        addToHomescreen();
});
```

When I run the "developper server" on 3000 port, I don't get any log when I use the jquery code.

I'm using apache passenger on ubuntu for a rails back-end and the front-end runs on jquery-3.1.1

I tried to use rack-cors but it did not change anything.

I disabled adBlockPlus plugin too but it did not change either.

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected response?

Comment: When you do Ajax call, what does your DevTools network tab shows? Does response comes with 200 code or 404/500/403? What's the response from URL?

Comment: The expected response is 200 and the json data I'm requesting.

Comment: @Justinas : The network tab shows the line with the call and "(failed)" status, "xhr" type, "0B" size and "2ms" time.

Comment: @galettan Can you provide actual request url? Also, make sure you output correct JSON, otherwise your Ajax will fail because of `dataType: "application/json",`

Comment: the fact that I see sub.domain.com and the query has `crossDomain: true` makes me ask is this a cross domain request and if so, does the sub.domain.com server respond with CORS headers

Comment: @JaromandaX : I guess you're right but I can't figure out why since I configured rack-cors. :-(

Comment: @Justinas: I'd rather not, but when using postman / chrome / safari I get a perfect json.

Comment: using postman means never having a cors issue ... look at the request response headers in developer tools console/network tab ... do the CORS headers look correct to you?

Comment: @JaromandaX : That's the point, I don't get any response. But I asked a friend to check and he gets a "No allow-control-access-origin" header is missing... So I guess rack-cors doesn't work properly.

Comment: can you see the request at all? if not, the request isn't even being made, so your problem is in the code ... or perhaps you're browser developer tools aren't setup to display xhr requests - which browser are you dealing with

Comment: @JaromandaX : I can see the request, but the result is "failed" with no response. http://hpics.li/b55a2b0

Comment: that's not a very useful developer tools - what browser is that

Comment: @JaromandaX Google chrome

Comment: so when you click on the request, it should show you the request and response headers and all sorts of things besides

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes but it doesn't :-(.
Actually I enabled CORS on my apache server but it doesn't seem to work. The friend who had the no header pb has now the same problem as I do.
What really bothers me is that I don't get any log on my API access log while loading this page.